# Is it possible to have a Git repo in Windows Azure?

Tags: windows, git, azure

Does anyone know if it's possible to have a Git repo hosted on Windows Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't anything ready for Windows Azure, But you can create one, since Git can be used over http. You can use GitSharp or DotGit libraries.